# How do I make new messages appear on left/right depending on who sent them? (No Float)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a webpage where, depending on whether user 1(left textarea) or user 2(right textarea) sends a message, the message in the yellow conversation window appears on left or right, same way the messaging looks on phones nowadays. It's distinguishable who sent the message by the background color of the message sent, user 1 is lighter blue, user 2 is purple. I'm trying to do this without using float, so please don't suggest that. Here's the code:

```js
function Send(ele) {
  var br = document.createElement("br");
  var foo = document.getElementById("conversation");
  foo.appendChild(br);
  var para = document.createElement("label");
  var txt;
  if (ele.id == "btn") {
    txt = document.getElementById("text");
    var node = document.createTextNode(txt.value);
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("conversation");
    para.className = 'message';
    element.appendChild(para);
  } else {
    txt = document.getElementById("text2");
    var node = document.createTextNode(txt.value);
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("conversation");
    para.className = 'message2';
    element.appendChild(para);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 5% 10% 0% 10%;
  background-color: azure;
}

#conversation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center,
}

.user {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.user2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}

.message,
.message2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 50%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: white;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2%;
}

.message2 {
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: right;
}


/*23*/
```

```html
<div id="conversation">
  <div class="message">
    <label>On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. </label>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="message2">
    <label>On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="user">
    <input id="text" type="textarea" />
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Send" onclick="Send(this)">
  </div>
  <div class="user2">
    <input id="btn2" type="button" value="Send" onclick="Send(this)">
    <input id="text2" type="textarea" />

  </div>
</div>
```

I've also uploaded it to jsfiddle to save you guys the trouble:

https://jsfiddle.net/pbzqw278/

If it's not too much trouble, would you also explain why you did what you did, since css is still kind of a gray area to me.

Comment: how about set the "chat-bubble"-style with "position:relaitve" and "left:10px"/"right:10px"?

Comment: message and message 2 classes are supposed to be the chat-bubble and I've set its position to relative already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use flex and row wrapper. Each message could have a `display: flex;` row and then messages set to respectively `align-self: flex-start;` and `align-self: flex-end;`. I have edited your snippet to reflect it.

```js
function Send(ele) {
  var foo = document.getElementById("conversation");
  var rowWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  rowWrapper.className = 'message-row';
  var para = document.createElement("label");
  var txt;
  if (ele.id == "btn") {
    txt = document.getElementById("text");
    var node = document.createTextNode(txt.value);
    para.appendChild(node);
    para.className = 'message';
    rowWrapper.appendChild(para);
    var element = document.getElementById("conversation");
    element.appendChild(rowWrapper);
  } else {
    txt = document.getElementById("text2");
    var node = document.createTextNode(txt.value);
    para.appendChild(node);
    para.className = 'message2';
    rowWrapper.appendChild(para);
    var element = document.getElementById("conversation");
    element.appendChild(rowWrapper);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 5% 10% 0% 10%;
  background-color: azure;
}

#conversation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center,
}

.user {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.user2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}

.message-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}

.message,
.message2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 50%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: white;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2%;
}

.message {
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.message2 {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: right;
}


/*23*/
```

```html
<div id="conversation">
    <div class="message-row">
        <div class="message">
            <label>On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-row">
        <div class="message2">
            <label>On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="user">
        <input id="text" type="textarea" />
        <input id="btn" type="button" value="Send" onclick="Send(this)">
    </div>
    <div class="user2">
        <input id="btn2" type="button" value="Send" onclick="Send(this)">
        <input id="text2" type="textarea" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just in case - I've updated the answer as I forgot about JS update.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, do you know where I can learn more about display flex and align flex?

Comment: There are couple of cool ways to do this, with games: http://flexboxfroggy.com/, http://www.flexboxdefense.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by setting `display: block` to both `.message` and `.message2`, and adding `margin-left: auto` to `.message2`.

I would also adjust the `max-width` to about `48%`.

You can move some css properties from the `div` to the `label`. This will allow the width of the text to determine the width of the `background-color`.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/sy7kcLj7/2/)

```css
body {
  margin: 5% 10% 0% 10%;
  background-color: azure;
}

#conversation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center,
}

.user {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.user2 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}

.message,
.message2 {
  max-width: 48%;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2%;
  display: block;
}

.message2 {
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}

.message label,
.message2 label {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  color: white;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.message2 label {
  background-color: purple;
}


/*23*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="conversation">
    <div class="message">
      <label>On insensible possession!</label>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="message2">
      <label>On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books
        arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. </label>
    </div>
    <div class="message2">
      <label>On insensible</label>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <label>On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. </label>
    </div>
    <div class="message2">
      <label>On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="user">
      <input id="text" type="textarea" />
      <input id="btn" type="button" value="Send" onclick="Send(this)">
    </div>
    <div class="user2">
      <input id="btn2" type="button" value="Send" onclick="Send(this)">
      <input id="text2" type="textarea" />

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This does solve the positioning, however it also causes the message bubble to be 50% wide no matter the text amount, I need it to be only as wide as the text

Comment: @WhatAmIDoing I've updated the answer. I just moved some CSS from the `div` to the `label`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your if clause where you check from which button it has been send I would add a position to the TextNode.

You can add CSS Style via Javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById("myTextNode").style.left = "5px;";
```

You have to add an ID to the TextNode obviously and based on your code I'm sure you know how to do via Javascript :). Just in case:

```
node.id = "someID";
```

Comment: No reason to use JS in here.